# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "sanseacabó"?

Tags: etimología

Recordaba en estos días la palabra *sanseacabó* y al buscar en el DLE, no aparece la etimología de la misma. Revisando en internet, encontré este [sitio](http://www.blasita.com/origen-de-sanseacabo/), que plantea hipótesis probables, aunque queda una cierta duda (al ser varias hipótesis y ser solo una fuente, debe revisarse bien).

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a buscar el origen de la palabra *sanseacabó*?

Comment: Me gusta la pregunta.  Me encanta la palabra *sanseacabó*.

Comment: La etimología no aparece porque está clara: el propio DLE te dice que también se puede escribir "san se acabó". Más que la etimología, lo interesante realmente será el origen, es decir, a quién se le ocurrió, cuándo se originó, etc., tal y como expresas en el último párrafo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión aparece en el DLE en 1925:

> SANSEACABÓ. expr. fam. con que se da por terminado un asunto.

Aunque en el CORDE podemos encontrar la expresión ya en siglo XIX, curiosamente siempre escrita por parte del mismo autor:

> *Ese padre Guatemala es un cubiletero que los trae a ustedes embaucados hablándoles de la otra vida. Eso de que haya otro mundo es pampirolada; pues los hombres no pasamos de ser como los relojes, que rota la cuerda, ¡crac!, san se acabó.*
>
> Ricardo Palma, "Tradiciones peruanas, primera serie", 1872 (Perú).

En la hemeroteca de la BNE podemos encontrar la expresión en su forma *sanseacabó* desde 1875, pero hay casos anteriores en su forma *san se acabó*, siendo la primera [la siguiente](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004388551&page=10&search=%22san%20se%20acab%C3%B3%22&lang=es):

> [...] este año mandan las armas ó manda Alaix, ó Espartero, ó quien sea, y san-se-acabó [...].
>
> Fr. Gerundio (periódico satírico de política y costumbres). 1/1/1839, página 10.

Hay en el diccionario expresiones similares, como por ejemplo esta del *Diccionario de autoridades*:

> Santas *Páscuas*. Modo de hablar con que alguno se conforma facilmente, con lo que ha sucedido, ù otro dice.

El prefijo *san* o *santo* se puede usar como adjetivo cuando algo es "útil, deleitable o al gusto", al estilo de *bendito*:

> *Con esta santa medicina, quedó mi rostro en el color natural que me diste.*
>
> Catalina de Jesús Herrera, "Secretos entre el alma y Dios", a 1765 (Ecuador).

Por otro lado, era normal usar expresiones con "se acabó" para terminar discusiones o cosas en general:

> El Deán [...] luego que oyó decir que había indios por los cerros, se vistió de militar, y muy bien armado salió por las calles en busca de sus soldados los clérigos; y se acabó con esto la procesión, que ya estaba empezando [...].
>
> Anónimo, "Copia de carta remitida con propio a la Paz", 1781 (Perú).
>
> ---
>
> Si aquí no gusta, que se jiben, y se acabó lo que se daba.
>
> Juan Valera, "Correspondencia", 1847-1857 (España).

Si unimos el uso de "y se acabó" con el uso de "san/santo" para enfatizar (al estilo de "y santas pascuas"), surge "y sanseacabó". El uso de "y santas pascuas" para expresar que uno se conforma con algo sucedido se transforma en "y san se acabó", para indicar que el que tiene que conformarse es la persona con la que hablas, dado que la discusión se terminó.